# Spring MVC RequestParam Long Type Binding Always Null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In one of the actions that I have, I've binded a Long (not primitive) type to a request parameter.

```
@RequestMapping("/history")
    public ModelAndView historyList_GET(
            @RequestParam(value="startDate",required=false) Long startDate,
            @RequestParam(value="endDate",required=false) Long endDate
            )
    {
    }
```

But the values of those variables are always null. So I've checked docs, searched a similar problem but I've found nothing.

Of course, I could change binding type to String and then convert it to Long but that's not a good solution in my opinion. That's just a workaround...

Another way that I've seen that people using wrapper object to bind it with @ModelAttribute annotation. Such as;

```
public class Wrapper
{
 public Long startDate;
 public Long endDate;
}

@RequestMapping("/history")
    public ModelAndView historyList_GET(
            @ModelAttribute Wrapper dates
            )
{
}
```

but then again this is also a workaround.

I'm asking how this could be possible ? Why even though all other reference types binds perfectly, Long doesn't ? Is it because something I've missed ?

These are the requests by the way...

```
/history?endDate=144656539476
/history?startDate=144656539476
/history?startDate=144656539476&endDate=14499999999
```

Comment: You must have missed something, the code you provided works well and parameters are bound as expected. Are you sure that this particular method executes when request is sent? btw. `@ModelAttribute` is used for little bit different cases

Comment: Method is executed when request is given, I'm sure of it. As for the part that I'm missing something, I also thought about that but, it's a very simple method, it should be binding it... I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: Can you reproduce problem on some public repository?

Answer (score 0):

Your wrapper class is missing setter methods.

Actual code of wrapper class which worked for me:-

```
public class Wrapper {
    public Long startDate;
    public Long endDate;

    public Long getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Long startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Long getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Long endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

}
```